# PHP-Elasticsearch Search through all the indexes

Tags: php, elasticsearch, nosql

We have configured ElasticSearch to create different index based on the date.

```
health status index                         pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.20   5   1      85636            0       27mb           27mb 
yellow open   .kibana                         1   1          2            0      9.6kb          9.6kb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.21   5   1     108346            0     37.7mb         37.7mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.22   5   1      58172            0     22.1mb         22.1mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.19   5   1      11535            0      3.6mb          3.6mb
```

Now we have to make a query for to fetch the logs against a particular field from all the indexes.

From the [PHP-ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_quickstart.html), I understand that it is easy to query a particular index.

But how to query all the indexes at once?

Answer (score 0):

You have to query for `'index' => '*'`

> * is a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_all` or empty string to refer to all indices: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php#L814

> $params['index']                    = (list) A comma-separated list of index names to search; use `_all` or empty string to perform the operation on all indices

Answer (score 0):

Searching for different indexes works in the same way as searching for in a single index. You do not need to change anything in your query. You can use _all or like Vuldo mentioned '*' which is a wild card as the value for you index or just leave it empty and it will search all types in all indices.

You can take a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-index-multi-type.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana, you would search all docs with request below:

GET YOUR_INDEX_NAME/_search

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

same for php, you create a same request body but with different syntax and would look like this:

```
[
    "query" => [
        "match_all" => new \stdClass()
    ]
]
```